# Received "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" in Windows app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows

In my windows app, i am trying to load an image from local machine to server but facing an exception of  `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` on the statement `StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();`. Here is the method:

```
FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        // Set the image source to the selected bitmap 
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 600; //match the target Image.Width, not shown
        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
        big_image.Source = bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

How to fix it ??? I am using VS '13. `Big_image` is the image defined in `xaml` and i am trying to set its source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i got the solution by adding some new stuff:

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
   {
      using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
      {
           // Set the image source to the selected bitmap 
           BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
           await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
           big_image.Source = bitmapImage;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

[microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is used to pick images.